# df.show() is not working - Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o95.showString

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to solve the problems from O'Reilly book of Learning Spark.

Below part of code is working fine

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

# define schema for our data
schema = StructType([
StructField("Id", IntegerType(), False),
StructField("First", StringType(), False),
StructField("Last", StringType(), False),
StructField("Url", StringType(), False),
StructField("Published", StringType(), False),
StructField("Hits", IntegerType(), False),
StructField("Campaigns", ArrayType(StringType()), False)])

#create our data
data = [[1, "Jules", "Damji", "https://tinyurl.1", "1/4/2016", 4535, ["twitter", "LinkedIn"]],
   [2, "Brooke","Wenig","https://tinyurl.2", "5/5/2018", 8908, ["twitter", "LinkedIn"]],
   [3, "Denny", "Lee", "https://tinyurl.3","6/7/2019",7659, ["web", "twitter", "FB", 
"LinkedIn"]],
   [4, "Tathagata", "Das","https://tinyurl.4", "5/12/2018", 10568, ["twitter", "FB"]],
   [5, "Matei","Zaharia", "https://tinyurl.5", "5/14/2014", 40578, ["web", "twitter", "FB", 
"LinkedIn"]],
   [6, "Reynold", "Xin", "https://tinyurl.6", "3/2/2015", 25568, ["twitter", "LinkedIn"]]
  ]
 # main program
 if __name__ == "__main__":
 # create a SparkSession
spark = (SparkSession
   .builder
   .appName("Example-3_6")
   .getOrCreate())
# create a DataFrame using the schema defined above
blogs_df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)
```

But when I am trying to execute .show(), I am getting java error. Can somebody help me on how do I resolve this error ?

```
blogs_df.show()
```

Error :
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o95.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 3) (<>.<>.com executor driver): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python3": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:165)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:107)
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:119)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:145)

---

At the same time when I am executing below code, I am getting the result of df.show()

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, IntegerType, StringType
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession

schema = StructType() \
.add("city", StringType(), True) \
.add("state", StringType(), True) \
.add("pop", IntegerType(), True)

df_with_schema1 = spark.read.format("csv") \
  .option("delimiter", ",") \
  .option("header", True) \
  .schema(schema) \
  .load("<directory>\\pyspark-test.csv")

df_with_schema1.show()
```

Comment: what is the spark and python version

Comment: spark - 3.1.2
python - 3.8.3

Comment: There is definitely something wrong with your machine python environment. Or make sure you have proper indentation in your python code. Also If you say the second code sample is running where are you running it as it does not have main method and you are not creating spark session in it.

Answer (score -2):

You most likely don't have Python installed properly. Also gave this a try

```py
spark = (SparkSession
   .builder
   .master('local[*]') # add this
   .appName("Example-3_6")
   .getOrCreate())
```

Comment: tried this now, not worked
At the same time when I am executing below code , it is working fine
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, IntegerType, StringType
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession

schema = StructType() \
.add("city", StringType(), True) \
.add("state", StringType(), True) \
.add("pop", IntegerType(), True)

df_with_schema1 = spark.read.format("csv") \
      .option("delimiter", ",") \
      .option("header", True) \
      .schema(schema) \
      .load("<directory>\\pyspark-test.csv")
df_with_schema1.show()